Woocommerce Product Attributes - Term Invalid Taxonomy
On first run the script will throw an error with Invalid Taxonomy, on second run it ingests fine. When pausing with xdebug it fires correctly, so appears to be a time gate issue. I notice after the first run that the global attributes don't have any terms assigned, where after the second run everything is assigned correctly.
Block in question
if (! $term = get_term_by( 'name', $option, $term_name )) { // $option='Small', $term_name='pa_size'
    // WP_Error Invalid Taxonomy
    wp_insert_term( $option, $term_name );
    $term = get_term_by( 'name', $option, $term_name );
}

Have also tried
wp_set_object_terms($po->get_id(), $option, $term_name, true );

Full code
// Add global attributes.
$global_attributes = ['Size', 'Colour'];
foreach ($global_attributes as $global_attribute) {
    wc_create_attribute([
        'name' => $global_attribute,
        'type' => 'text',
    ]);
}
// Add product.
$product_attributes = [
    'Size' => ['Small', 'Large', 'Medium'],
    'Colour' => ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green'],
    'Rating' => '5 Star!'
];

$product = new \WC_Product();

foreach ($product_attributes as $name => $value) {
    $attribute = new \WC_Product_Attribute();
    $attribute->set_name($name);
    $attribute->set_options([$value]);

    if(is_array($value)) {
        $attribute->set_options($value);
    }

    if (in_array($name, $global_attributes)) {
        // Convert name to pa_name
        $term_name = wc_attribute_taxonomy_name( $name );
        $options = [];
        
        if(is_array($value)) {
            foreach($value as $option) {
                if (! $term = get_term_by( 'name', $option, $term_name )) {
                    // WP_Error Invalid Taxonomy
                    wp_insert_term( $option, $term_name );
                    $term = get_term_by( 'name', $option, $term_name );
                }
                $options[] = $term->term_id;

            }
        } else {
            if (! $term = get_term_by( 'name', $value, $term_name )) {
                wp_insert_term( $value, $term_name );
                $term = get_term_by( 'name', $value, $term_name );
            }
            $options[] = $term->term_id;
        }
        
        $attribute->set_id(wc_attribute_taxonomy_id_by_name( $name ));
        $attribute->set_name($term_name);
        $attribute->set_options($options);
    }
}
$product->save();


I think that all WordPress taxonomies (or custom taxonomies) need to exist first in order to be able to set any term for it (note that each (global) WooCommerce product attribute is a custom taxonomy itself).

@LoicTheAztec Thanks, that put me on the correct track. Needed to register the taxonomy to force it to be available right away. Otherwise it will register automatically on page refresh, which is why it works the second run.

Replaced wc_create_attribute() with a call to a custom function createAttribute() found on another stack answer. Registering the taxonomy will happen on page load, since the taxonomy is needed right away, we register it ourselves.
function createAttribute(string $attributeName, string $attributeSlug): ?\stdClass {
    delete_transient('wc_attribute_taxonomies');
    \WC_Cache_Helper::invalidate_cache_group('woocommerce-attributes');

    $attributeLabels = wp_list_pluck(wc_get_attribute_taxonomies(), 'attribute_label', 'attribute_name');
    $attributeWCName = array_search($attributeSlug, $attributeLabels, TRUE);

    if (! $attributeWCName) {
        $attributeWCName = wc_sanitize_taxonomy_name($attributeSlug);
    }

    $attributeId = wc_attribute_taxonomy_id_by_name($attributeWCName);
    if (! $attributeId) {
        $taxonomyName = wc_attribute_taxonomy_name($attributeWCName);
        unregister_taxonomy($taxonomyName);
        $attributeId = wc_create_attribute(array(
            'name' => $attributeName,
            'slug' => $attributeSlug,
            'type' => 'text'
        ));

        register_taxonomy($taxonomyName, apply_filters(
                'woocommerce_taxonomy_objects_' . $taxonomyName, 
                array(
                    'product'
                )
            ), 
            apply_filters('woocommerce_taxonomy_args_' . $taxonomyName, 
                array(
                    'labels' => array(
                        'name' => $attributeSlug,
                    ),
                    'hierarchical' => FALSE,
                    'show_ui' => FALSE,
                    'query_var' => TRUE,
                    'rewrite' => FALSE,
                )
            )
        );
    }

    return wc_get_attribute($attributeId);
}

